.NET Core How to validate a jwt token using a keycloak certificate?
The frontend uses Keycloak which generates a jwt token. I am sending this token in the Authorization header to the server.
The problem is how to validate the token received from a third-party resource on the server?
The server is written in .Net Core (Net 8) and is used to implement the REST API. The frontend is not written in ASP.NET
I was able to do the following:

Extract the jwt token from the header;
To get keycloak certificates using a request to {{keyclockUrl}}/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/OpenID-connect/certs'.
Extract the line with the tag x5c from the certificates, which contains the certificate itself and convert it toX509Certificate2.

Now I have both a token and a certificate, but I do not know how to validate the token.
Similar solutions use storing the secret key directly on the server, but this is a bad practice, keylock for security to reissue keys every couple of months
Am I moving in the right direction?
Or are there other ways to verify the jwt token generated by keylock?
UPDATE:
The solution I found:

Download the list of certificates from {{keyclockUrl}}/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/OpenID-connect/certs. Get the key with "use": "sig" in the field `x5c' there is a chain of certificates in the form of strings.
2.Converting strings to certificates and extracting keys:

List<X509SecurityKey> keyList = [];
foreach (var x5c in (dynamic)x5cList)
{
    var _certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(x5c.ToString()));
    keyList.Add(new X509SecurityKey(_certificate));
}


Now you can use these keys in Etoken ValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys and validate the token:

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
try
{
    var claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out var validatedToken);
    if (claims != null && validatedToken != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}


The token has been successfully validated


Not C# version but this answer helps to verify the steps.

@BenchVue Thanks for the link to the good stuff

Since keycloak claims OIDC compatibility, you should be able to just use out of the box MicrosoftAspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package. Documentation is available here.
